# Postgres - run part of a query N times

Tags: postgresql

I have a summary table that looks something like this:

```
user_id         year      month     amount    type
--------------------------------------------------
5               2018      1         100       Foo
6               2017      12        100       Bar
6               2018      11        100       Foo
6               2018      12        100       Bar
7               2018      12        100       Foo
7               2019      12        100       Bar
8               2019      12        100       Foo
```

I needed a way to calculate latest the totals / averages (among other things) for certain users,
for example, for users 6 and 7, I would get:

```
user_id         year      month     amount     type
---------------------------------------------------
6               2018      12        100        Bar
7               2019      12        100        Foo
```

and add average it so it returns the below result:

```
totalOrderAmount averageOrderAmount numberOfFoos numberOfBars
-------------------------------------------------------------------
300              100                2            1
```

Originally this needed to be done for the current / previous periods, which I did using the following query (thanks to the help of another post):

```
with d as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by user_id  order by year desc, month desc ) rn
  from  monthly_order_summary 
  where user_id in (6, 7)
) 
select * from
(
    select  'CURRENT' as period,
            SUM(order_amount) as totalOrderAmount, 
            AVG(order_amount) as averageOrderAmount,
            count(*) filter (where order_type = 'UNMODIFIED') as numberOfFoos,
            count(*) filter (where order_type = 'UNKNOWN') as numberOfBars
    from d
    where  rn <= 1
    UNION
    select  'PREVIOUS' as period,
            SUM(order_amount) as totalOrderAmount, 
            AVG(order_amount) as averageOrderAmount,
            count(*) filter (where order_type = 'UNMODIFIED') as numberOfFoos,
            count(*) filter (where order_type = 'UNKNOWN') as numberOfBars
    from d
    where  rn <= 2    
) as periods;
```

This will return 2 rows, but now I need to be able to do this for N number of periods, is there a way to loop the inner section n times, or a better solution?

I've looked at while loops, but I'm not sure how to implement them in this situation, or if that is even the correct way to go, there is no upper limit to N theoretically, but in reality it shouldn't go more than 120. Most of the time it will be 60 or lower.

**UPDATE:** I apologize for not being clear, the final result should look something like this:

```
year month totalOrderAmount averageOrderAmount numberOfFoos numberOfBars
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021 7     300              100                2            1
2021 6     200              100                2            1
2021 5     500              100                2            1
...
```

so it's not total per user, but for the totals for a group of users for each year / month line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, year, month, amount, avg(amount) over w, sum(amount) over w, sum(case when type = Foo then 1 else 0 end) over w, sum(case when type = Bar then 1 else 0 end) over w  from monthly_order_summary window w as (partition by user_id order by year desc, month desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

something like this?

Comment: Hi, this seems to be grouping / totaling each user as a row, I need the total per month / year, please look at the updated description. I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: Not sure what this does exactly but it seems to be having a problem with 'and current': syntax error at or near "and"
LINE 3: month desc range UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and current)

Comment: The window partitions the data per user_id and orders the data descending by year and month. The window will look back unbounded rows, but it will not look ahead of the current row. When you calculate the sum, you will see that for each new record the sum will be updated with all previous records and the current one.

Comment: fixed it for you now